# TLayout to AutoSize along with TLabel

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am using latest Delphi 10.1 and creating a multi-device app. I have a `TLayout` that has `Align` set to `top`. I have a `TLabel` that is with in the mentioned `TLayout` and has `Align` set to `Client` and its `TLabel.AutoSize` set to `True`.

Problem is that when I have long label text, `TLabel` grows but `TLayout` doesn't grow.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to have the `TLayout`? If not, align the label `Top`, then with `AutoSize` and `WordWrap` it will grow downwards as needed.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Yes I need layout because I need to have a button next to label. I was hoping that layout would have some AutoSize property similar to label.

Comment: I don't understand why you need the Autosize on if the align is client.

Comment: @MikeD Its Align client to TLayout and not form.

Answer (score 1):

You know the new size of the label as soon as you change its text.
`Label.Width` will update to reflect the resized width.

You have 3 options.

1. Everytime you change the text of the label, also read its `width` and update the associated TLayout to match (not recommended).
2. Assign the `OnResize` event of the label and do something like this (recommended):

```
    procedure TForm45.Label1Resize(Sender: TObject);
    const
      ExtraWidthOfLayout = 10;
    var
      Lbl: TLabel;
      Layout: TLayout;
    begin
      if (Sender is TLabel) and (TLabel(Sender).Parent is TLayout) then begin
        Lbl:= TLabel(Sender);
        Layout:= TLayOut(Lbl.Parent);
        Layout.Width:= Lbl.Width + ExtraWidthOfLayout;
      end;
    end;
```

Note that you can use the same event for all labels.

3. Create a new control consisting of a fused layout and Label that overrides `TLabel.DoResize`.

Comment: It's about height I imagine.

Comment: @Johan Yes its about height.

Comment: @AlirezaNazari, no. This code is trivial to translate to C. the only problem is `is` and that you can google.